# Read data from X pointer and save it in an array - AVR Asm

Tags: assembly, avr, uart, atmega, atmel

I'm learning Avr Assembly. I'm writing a project that reads a uart string, then the string has to be saved in an array. Then the string has to be send back on the uart TX pin. I'm programming a ATMEGA8 microcontroller. I'm not sure everything is correct and probably some code will not be correct since I'm a starter in ASM avr.

first, I call the 'gets' subroutine to get the data from the uart pins.
(I have the code from http://www.rjhcoding.com/avr-asm-uart.php)

```
gets:
    in      r17, UCSRA      
    sbrs    r17, RXC
    rjmp    gets

    in      r16, UDR        ; gets received character 

    cpi     r16, $0D        ; check if rcv'd char is CR (enter)
    breq    gets_end        ; branch if CR 

    st      X+,r16          ; store char in buffer 
    rjmp    gets            ; get another char 

gets_end: 
    ldi     r16, $00
    st      X+,r16
    ret
```

But what I don't get about this code, how do I read the data in the X buffer and put it in a new Array? And how do I make and use that array?

Comment: `X` is a pointer register; once this code is done running, X will point to the *end* of the buffer; `st X+, r16` is post-increment addressing, like `*X++ = r16` in C I'm pretty sure.  You need to keep track of the start address you passed to it in the first place, and start again looping over that buffer.  Are you sure you want to copy it, instead of just reading it?  You could receive into a new buffer, or just process the current data and then let it get overwritten.  "making an array" is just a matter of reserving space anywhere, on the stack or in static storage or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! No it's not really necessary to copy the data in a new buffer. Do I need to do anything for reserve some space for the buffer? I'm still a noob in this topic... Do you maybe have a sort of example code?

Comment: If you can write a minimal example of something in C, you can get a C compiler to make AVR code for you.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/vTKjPT8jW. (Not sure why it takes GCC so much asm to subtract 16 from the stack pointer). Use space on the stack, static storage, or even call malloc if you're using a dynamic allocator.